# Placeholder in Internet Explorer 8 & 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Guys I know this question has been asked here many time but still I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem. I have a `textarea` in my asp.net mvc application which has a placeholder in it.

```
<textarea placeholder="Write Query..." maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```

Now Internet Explorer 8 & 9 doesn't support the placeholder property so I need some workaround for it, I have search here and google and found various javascripts but unfortunately none of those worked. Although some worked (as the showed the placeholder text) but the text didn't disappear on writing in the `textArea`

Two of those scripts (that worked half right) are these :

```
$(function () {
    if (!$.support.placeholder) {
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        });
        $('input[type="text"], textarea').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function () { $(this).val(''); });
        });
    }
});
```

Second :

```
$(function () {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 9) {
        $("[placeholder]").focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
        }).blur();

        $("[placeholder]").parents("form").submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you'll need to to differentiate your question from the others or this'll get closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to this alternative

https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim/

i think it's can manage by meta tag

Comment: Better to mark the question as duplicate rather than linking to that question.